# How to declare an array in TypeScript that can be one of many types, recursively, that must be all the same type

Tags: typescript, types, typing

I have been struggling to create a type to satisfy this data model:

```
Each node can be:
  - native type
    - string, number, boolean, null, undefined 
  - a list containing all the *same type* of nodes
  - a dictionary of any type of nodes
```

It is trivial to create a type such as this:

```js
type Native = string | number | boolean | null | undefined;
type List = Array<Native | List | Dictionary>;
type Dictionary = { [key: string]: Native | List | Dictionary };

type Node = Native | List | Dictionary;
```

However, this fails to assert that all members in an array are of the same type.
For example, I need to satisfy these cases:

```js
const value: Node = ["foo", "bar"]    // Valid
const value: Node = ["foo", 1]        // Invalid, all are Native types, but not the same type
const value: Node = []                // Valid, empty arrays should be valid too
const value: Node = 4;                // Valid, Nodes can be native values too
const value: Node = {
  a: 1,
  b: "foo",
  c: [ [1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"] ],
  d: {
    e: {},
  },
};                                    // Valid
```

However, if `c: [ [1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", 4] ],` in the last case above, then the entire declaration should be invalid.

How can I do this? Ideally, I would need to be able to change what native types are allowed using a `Native` type union, as in the example.

Comment: What is the original intent of creating such a type?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this is probably not the best solution but it was the closest thing I could come up with.

Instead of defining the `Native`, define each of the arrays that your type will expect and then derive native via `[number]` syntax as shown:

```js
type AllowedArrays = string[] | number[] | boolean[] | null[] | undefined[];
type Native = AllowedArrays[number];
type List = List[] | Dictionary[] | AllowedArrays;
type Dictionary = { [key: string]: Native | List | Dictionary };
```

This way you still have a single source of truth for what is allowed. Doing the opposite might be possible but I lack the skills to achieve that.

Hope this is still able to help.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WG6jom)